# Android Distance Between Several Locations

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am working on a app that needs to find closest store.

1) I have method to find current location
2) I have list of several hundred postcodes
3) I also have method that will convert postcodes to Long/Lat

What I need is a good solution to check closest distance between each store.

Any thoughts on a good way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the distance formula:

[image]

This will give the distance between two points, in your case longitude and latitude.

Where `x` and `y` are longitude and latitude respectably.

Comment: Thanks for this.. Is there any way of avoiding comparing one location with five hundred others.

Comment: @SamBrown If you don't compare to the others then how can you find the distance?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want Euclidian distance for this case, what you're probably looking for is the Haversine function. Considering you're working with Lat/Long couples. Javascript code can be found here: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html . Shouldn't be too hard to convert it to Java.